# How to use CRUDRepository to save a list but commit at the end

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a project that need to save a list of item, but what I want to do is I want it save all items in the list if they all success, but if any of them failed during the save action, I want all changes for items in the list not committed by using `CRUDRespository`.

Controller:

```
@PostMapping
ResponseEntity<List<ItemResource>> save(@RequestBody final List<ItemResource> itemResourceList){
    List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();

    for (final ItemResource itemResource : ItemResourceList)
        {
         final Item savedItem = itemService.save(resourceToEntity(itemResource));
         itemList.add(savedItem);
        }

}
```

service just repository.save(item);

and repository just a repository extends CrudRepository.

I want it go through the list try to save all items, but commit at the end of the list done, if anything happened during saving items in the list, then do not commit any changes.

if this is possible.

thanks

Comment: checkout spring @Transactional

Comment: There's an example at the end of [this page](http://zetcode.com/springboot/crudrepository/)

Answer (score 0):

itemService class should be annotated with @Repository and should extend
CrudRepository

then try creating bean of itemService itemService = context
  .getBean(itemService.class);

then use itemService.save(resourceToEntity(itemResource))